# Is there a way to avoid 404 pages in Wordpress?

Tags: errors, 404-error, seo, google

On my site, people can link to non-existing posts, which is fine because that's the whole structure on my site... The problem is that you get 404 errors, which is not good for SEO. Is there a way in Wordpress to avoid 404 pages? So if a post not exists, that you can do else instead of sending to Google that it's a 404 page?

Comment: A 404 is appropriate for a _file that does not exist_ but what would you want to do instead? What is the "structure on [your] site" that makes you want to maintain broken links?

Comment: Once, I had a PHP website without a CMS. On there, the non existing links were not outputting 404 errors, but were going to a page where you can add that particular post. Google did not saw it as 404 pages. But Wordpress does this as it's default. So I want to know if it's possible (if so, how) to make it something else... Does not matter what, just something else.

Comment: So you have some kind of "front end posting" setup? You want users forwarded to a "create post" form for nonexistent post? Something like that?

Comment: Exactly. But once again, it does not matter actually where it goes to, I will find something, so long it does not say to Google that it's a 404 page... It is affecting the SEO and that's very very frustrating. The site can't grow because of it.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Is it possible? If no, would a redirection (301) of 404 pages be a solution for SEO?

Comment: Yes, you can do it but redirecting a lot of pages to the same "dummy" page will be just as bad. You will have huge duplicate content issues. You need a better plan to solve this, in my opinion.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10019/discussion-between-user1627363-and-s-ha-dum)

Comment: Can we discuss this in chat? I guess I don't want to give a 404 status in the header than. Before this site, I had a site that did not give that in the header and that was working very very well... The question is: how do I do that in Wordpress?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the [status_header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/status_header) filter. Adding the following to the functions.php file or your theme (or an appropriate plugin file) would do the trick:

```
add_filter( 'status_header', 'your_status_header_function', 10, 2 );

/**
 * Substitutes a 202 Accepted header for 404s.
 *
 * @param string $status_header The complete status header string
 * @param string $header HTTP status code
 * @return string $status_header
 */
function your_status_header_function( $status_header, $header ) {

    // if a 404, convert to 202
    if ( (int) $header == 404 )
        return status_header( 202 );

    // otherwise, return the unchanged header
    return $status_header;
}
```

Alternately, you could add `@header( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 202 Accepted', true, 202 );` to your 404.php file before the `get_header()` call.

The downside to this is that all 404s will be returned as 202, including legitimate Files Not Found.

Users will still be served the 404.php template, so add your create post form there and you should be good.

Comment: This _is_ what the OP wanted but I really do not think it is a good idea. I'd suggest at least sending a different header... perhaps 201, 204, 307, something besides "Everything is normal. All Good."

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea either. A 404 should be a 404.

Good thought on changing the response code. Do you think 201 or 202 is more appropriate?

Comment: I would think a 202 personally, a 201 is supposed to indicate something was created by the request right?

Comment: 202 would work too. I am improvising. There isn't really a header for "this page didn't exist when you tried to access it but we'll create one now so try again in a little bit".

Comment: Wikipedia uses a 404 page in this instance, TVTropes uses a 200. I'm editing my answer to return 202. I don't think it's precisely accurate either, but my meager understanding of the specs makes me think it's the closest match for what we're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

[Permalink Finder Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/permalink-finder/) serves that purpose.

Comment: Does it really?  The plugin's description indicates that it looks to find similarly-named pages/posts and redirects using a 301 header.  The OP wanted to send back a 200 header and allow the missing page to be added.